# Error 500 on nonexistent directory

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

My `.htaccess` is configured with the following code so that `prohackr112.tk/page1.html` and `prohackr112.tk/page2.php` are accessible via `prohackr112.tk/page1` and `prohackr112.tk/page2`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

But when I try to access a directory that is really an `html` file (e.g. `prohackr112.tk/page1/indir`), I get a 500 internal server error. Why is this not simply a 404 error? If this is a problem with my `.htaccess`, how can I configure it so that it *is* a 404 error?

**EDIT:**
When I try to go to `prohackr112.tk/page.html/indir` it just gives me `page.html`.

Comment: first stop for a 500 error: the server's error log. until you know EXACTLY what the error is, don't poke at random things trying to guess at what the problem is. could be a .htaccess syntax error, could be an infinite redirect loop, could be that someone peed in your Apache's cornflakes this morning and it's having a bad web day.

Comment: I first got this error about a week ago and it still gives me the same thing [here](http://prohackr112.tk/cube/cube). And I don't know how to find the error log; i'm using 000webhost...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```